# JQ - extract text with multiple regex expressions

Tags: json, jq

I have keys that sometimes looks like this `docker/nginx:latest` and sometimes looks like this `docker/nginx@sha256:9560f8528a3cd`

I can extract the image name between the Repo name and tag using the following

```
.image | match("(?<=\\/)(.*)(?=\\:)").captures[].string
```

However how do I add multiple conditions to capture both conditions ?

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
.image | match("(?<=\\/)(.*)(?=\\: | \\@)").captures[].string
```

Sample Json

```
{
 "image": "docker/nginx:latest"
}
```

or

```
{
 "image": "docker/nginx@sha256:9560f8528a3cd"
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding the spaces in your regex? They are not insignificant in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spaces that shouldn't be there (unless you add the `x` modifier), but the main issue is `.*` matches too much.

It was suggested that you replace `.*` with `.*?`, but that's a really bad habbit that will bite you one day. You should replace it with `[^:@]*` instead.

All you need is this:

```
.image | match("/([^:@]+)").captures[].string
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/h3OSR2ElUT9) on jqplay

Answer (score 2):

Remove the spaces and make the capture non-greedy by adding a `?` to `.*` (otherwise it will read until the `:` also in the second case):

```bash
.image | match("(?<=\\/)(.*?)(?=\\:|\\@)").captures[].string
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wttwqzvZk72)

You may also want to remove the escaping where it is not needed:

```bash
.image | match("(?<=/)(.*?)(?=:|@)").captures[].string
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xtY9q0J3E25)

Comment: `(?<=/)` can usually be replaced withe the more efficient `/\K`, although `/` suffices in this case. Also, `:|@` is usually written `[:@]`. But most importantly, using `.*?` as anything but an optimization is a bad practice that will bite you one day. Using `[^:@]+` is a far better solution (and one that requires less backtracking).

Comment: hmmm, the [docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE) lie about using [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/). The docs also say it uses Oniguruma, which apparently doesn't support `\K`. But the solution here is using `/`.